# Вылетает программа, при добавлении структуры в класс

Tags: c++, qt, классы, qt5

Куски программы, дам часть, ибо она очень большая и секретная)

**Как исправить вылет на 6 строке кода?**

Иерархия подключенных заголовочных файлов: **DataXY подключен к IOController, а он к MainWindow, а он к Main**

кусман метода из **IOController:**

**IOController.cpp:**

```
{//какой-то метод...
this->writeToBufferWin(answer);//В этой строке стало вылетать из-за кода 3 строками ниже
srand(time(0));

this->openUrl(this->linkJob);
this->randomSleep(1,2);

DataXY *dataScreen = new DataXY(this->searchButtonRunTask());//Вылет тут
//Если ее закоменнтить, вылетать не будет, но эта строка крайне важна
cout << "X: " << dataScreen->leftLowerBound.x <<endl;
}

DataXY IOController::searchButtonRunTask()
{//Создаю что статически, что динамически - вылетает
    QPixmap screenButton;
    DataXY *dataScreenXY = new DataXY(screenButton);
    dataScreenXY->searchButtonRunTask();
    return *dataScreenXY; //ТУТ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ПОЧЕМУ-ТО
}

bool IOController::writeToBufferWin(string str)
{
//    QClipboard *clipB = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
//    clipB->clear();
//    clipB->setText(QString::fromStdString(str));
//Если это расскоментировать и закомментировать то что ниже до ретерна, станет вылетать строка clipB->setText(QString::fromStdString(str));
   OpenClipboard(nullptr);
   EmptyClipboard();

   HGLOBAL hgBuffer;
   char* chBuffer;
   hgBuffer = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,(sizeof(str) * str.size()) + 1);
   chBuffer= (char*)GlobalLock(hgBuffer);
   strcpy(chBuffer, LPCSTR(str.c_str()));
   GlobalUnlock(hgBuffer);
   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgBuffer);
   CloseClipboard();
   return true;
}
```

**Конструктор DataXY, который срабатывает в коде:**

```
DataXY::DataXY(const QPixmap &pix)
{
   this->finishedSearchButtonStartTask = false;
   this->pixmap = pix;
   this->createScreen();
   this->screenDataHeight = this->pixmap.height();
   this->screenDataWidth = this->pixmap.width();
}
```

**Конструктор копирования, конструктор и деструктор DataXY**

```
void DataXY::createScreen()
{
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    if(screen)
    {
        this->pixmap = screen->grabWindow(0);
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error createing Screenshot" << endl;
    }
    delete screen;
}

DataXY::DataXY(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->createScreen();
    this->screenDataHeight=this->screenDataWidth=0;
    this->finishedSearchButtonStartTask = false;
}

DataXY::~DataXY()
{

}

DataXY::DataXY(const QPixmap &pix)
{
    this->finishedSearchButtonStartTask = false;

    this->pixmap = pix;
    this->createScreen();
    this->screenDataHeight = this->pixmap.height();
    this->screenDataWidth = this->pixmap.width();
//    this->img = this->pixmap.toImage();
}


DataXY::DataXY(const DataXY &dat)
{
    this->leftLowerBound = dat.leftLowerBound;
    this->leftUpperBound = dat.leftUpperBound;
    this->rightLowerBound = dat.rightLowerBound;
    this->rightUpperBound = dat.rightUpperBound;

    this->leftLowerMargin = dat.leftLowerMargin;
    this->leftUpperMargin = dat.leftUpperMargin;
    this->rightLowerMargin = dat.leftLowerMargin;
    this->rightUpperMargin = dat.leftUpperMargin;

    this->screenDataHeight = dat.getScreenDataHeight();
    this->screenDataWidth = dat.getScreenDataWidth();

    this->pixmap = dat.getPixmap();
//    this->img = this->pixmap.toImage();
    this->finishedSearchButtonStartTask = dat.finishedSearchButtonStartTask;

    this->createScreen();
}
```

Comment: Или напишите в комменты в какую сторону копать?

Comment: стек посмотрите, в этом коде сложно разобраться

Comment: Неизвестно что лежит в классе DataXY. Оператор присваивания/конструктор копирования у вас там написан?

Comment: А секретная потому-что програмка для заработка в интернете наподобие бота?

Comment: Да, бот для заработка на сайте одном

Comment: Зачем удалять то, что не Вами создавалось? ( delete screen; ). А Вы, видать с питона пришли раз всюду this пишете? И третье - в стеке обратных вызовов, наверняка, можно найти ошибку. Ну... или другим это поможет определить проблемное место.

Comment: @FrozenM Нет, мой первый язык с++, this пишу чисто для себя, чтобы точно не ошибится, где какой объект я меняю) Указатель на скрин вроде же я создаю? Или как ето работает.. Точнее я думал я создавал. Смотреть по стеку обратных вызовов я не умею, не умею этим пользоваться пока что(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Баг первый: вы выделяете память, и не удаляете. Это приводит к нехватке памяти и к краху системы.

```
{//какой-то метод...
DataXY *dataScreen = new DataXY(this->searchButtonRunTask());//Вылет тут
//Если ее закоменнтить, вылетать не будет, но эта строка крайне важна
cout << "X: " << dataScreen->leftLowerBound.x <<endl;
}
DataXY IOController::searchButtonRunTask()
{//Создаю что статически, что динамически - вылетает
    QPixmap screenButton;
    DataXY *dataScreenXY = new DataXY(screenButton);
    dataScreenXY->searchButtonRunTask();
    return *dataScreenXY; //ТУТ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ ПОЧЕМУ-ТО
}
```

Это исправляется если объект хранить в стеке:

```
{//какой-то метод...
DataXY dataScreen(this->searchButtonRunTask());//Вылет тут
//Если ее закоменнтить, вылетать не будет, но эта строка крайне важна
cout << "X: " << dataScreen.leftLowerBound.x <<endl;
}

DataXY IOController::searchButtonRunTask() {
  QPixmap screenButton;
  DataXY dataScreenXY(screenButton);
  dataScreenXY.searchButtonRunTask();
  return dataScreenXY; }
```

По поводу почему всё вылетает, вы не предоставили код деструктора класса `DataXY`, это очень поможет найти причину падения. Желательно весь код показывать, а то никто не сможет вам помочь.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста свой вк @AlexGlebe, скину проект, за исправление вылета могу заплатить вам символические 50р) Ну или сколько договоримся

Comment: Моя **Qt** библиотека несовместима с вашим кодом. Придётся смотреть вручную. Будем искать...

Comment: В `void DataXY::createScreen()` вы удаляете `screen`. Чует сердце, что зря.

Comment: А ведь точно! Нельзя его удалять было, правда я не понял почему... Ведь он создавался временно для получения QPixmap